# Modifying syscall_table.S while adding a system call in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am currently facing a problem in locating the syscall_table.S file in my arch/x86/kernel/ directory. In the online tutorail that i am following, it is gievn that i will find the file in this location. I am using linux-3.11.10. Please tell me how to locate this file. However, I have found this file in some other folders. If i were to modify one of these,which one should I modify ?
The following folders have syscall_table.S :
arch/microblaze/kernel
arch/m32r/kernel
arch/avr32/kernel
arch/parisc/kernel

Comment: YOU SHOULD READ http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific about what exactly you are trying to do.

sys_call_table is defined in arch/x86/kernel/syscall_64.c

The syscall entry is located in arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S

routines are associated with their syscall number in include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h and arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl

You might also want to look at include/linux/syscalls.h.